# Deploy standalone GUI Perl app on OS X

Tags: macos, perl, user-interface, desktop-application

What tools, apart from ActiveState's PerlApp, exist to bundle a Perl GUI application, libraries, interpreter, and all, into a standalone application on OS X?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used [PAR](http://par.perl.org/) to bundle a Perl/Tk app.

Comment: Does PAR allow you to wrap everything, including the Perl interpreter, in the bundle? I've read the docs on PAR and the answer to this question isn't entirely clear.

Comment: @KevinWalzer Given that OS X has Perl pre-installed, you may opt to build a bundle that uses the system's Perl and libraries, but yes, [`pp`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?pp) can build a binary with everything bundled.

Answer (score 2):

I have used Platypus from http://sveinbjorn.org/platypus/ in the past, but I'm not sure what it'll allow you to bundle

Comment: In principle, there's no reason why you shouldn't be able to include a full Perl installation within a Platypus app.